# How to reduce size of .mp3 file in raw folder to reduce size of .apk file in Android?

Tags: android, apk, filesize

In my android application , I am using more than 20 .mp3 files which are kept in raw folder.
So the problem is it cause huge apk file size.
Is there is any way to reduce size of .apk file by reducing size of .mp3 file?
OR it may required to convert .mp3 file to another suitable file format?
Which format?
Does anyone have any tips?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you define "huge"? I times where a game downloads multiple hundreds of mb, "huge" is kind of relative..

Comment: You can use Proguard tool for reduce the .apk file

Comment: Try to use 64bits for MP3 files

Comment: Apologizes for word "huge" .I will say big about 30 MB.But my intention is to reduce size of .apk

Answer (score 0):

You have different options. E.g. you can change the quality and kb/s. I agree to WarrenFaith that you should tell us what you mean by "huge". It might also make no sense to reduce the fileize.
You might try this tool with low quality: http://www.formatoz.com/

Answer (score 0):

Put your media files into asset folder. assets folder is compressed at the time when apk builds.